# Are products of independent random variables independent?

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence, proof

Let $Z_0, Z_1, Z_2,...$ be independent and identically distributed such that

$P(Z_n = 1) = P(Z_n = -1) = 1/2$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, ...$

Let $X_0 = Z_0$, $X_1 = X_0 Z_1$, $X_2 = X_1 Z_2$, ...

Are $X_0, X_1, X_2, ...$ independent?

---

What I tried:

We must prove that for Borel sets $B_1, ..., B_n$,

$$P(X_0 \in B_0, X_1 \in B_1, ..., X_n \in B_n) = \prod_{i=0}^{n} P(X_i \in B_i) \ (*) $$

since $X_0, X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are independent $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ iff $X_0, X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent.

1. $\{ X_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is Markov i.e.

$$P[X_n \in B| X_m] = P[X_n \in B| \mathscr{F}_m]$$

$\forall m \in [0,n], B \in \mathscr B$

[see proof in answer below]

This implies that LHS of (*) is equivalent to:

$$P(X_0 \in B_0) P(X_1 \in B_1 | X_0 \in B_0) ... P(X_n \in B_n | X_{n-1} \in B_{n-1})$$

2. $P(X_{n+1} = 1) = P(X_{n+1} = -1) = 1/2$ can be proven by induction by noting the recurrence relations:

$$P(X_{n+1} = 1) = P(X_n = 1)P(Z_{n+1} = 1) + P(X_n = -1)P(Z_{n+1} = -1)$$

$$P(X_{n+1} = -1) = P(X_n = 1)P(Z_{n+1} = -1) + P(X_n = -1)P(Z_{n+1} = 1)$$.

I made use of the fact that $X_n$ and $Z_{n+1}$ are independent, which follows from $X_n = Z_0Z_1 \dots Z_n$ and $Z_1, ..., Z_n$ and $Z_{n+1}$ are independent.

This makes the RHS of (*) to be $(1/2)^{n+1}$

3. $P(X_i \in B_i | X_{i-1} \in B_{i-1}) = 1/2$ because for $a_{n+1} \in \{-1, +1\}$

$P(X_{n+1} = a_{n+1} | X_n) = E[1_{X_{n+1} = a_{n+1}} | X_n] = E[1_{X_{n+1} = a_{n+1}} | X_n = 1]P(X_n = 1) + E[1_{X_{n+1} = a_{n+1}} | X_n = -1]P(X_n = - 1)$

This makes the LHS of (*) to be $(1/2)^{n+1}$ as well. QED

Any mistakes or missing steps?

Comment: Functions of independent variables are independent. So if $(X, Y)$ are independent from $(Z,T)$ then $f(X,Y)$ is independent from $g(Z,T)$.

Comment: Your new proof of the Markov property is wrong. In the notation of the linked alternative formulation, you need to consider more $f$s than just the identity..

Comment: @Student001 Thanks! Serves me right for trying to replace E's w/ P's. Anyway, edited OP and answer below

Comment: Sure thing. It's still wrong though; you are saying all those probabilities in the Markov statement are equal to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making this problem a lot harder than it needs to be because the
random variables in question are two-valued, and the problem can be
treated as one of independence of *events* rather than independence of
*random variables*.  In what follows, I will treat the independence of
*events* even though the events will be stated in terms of random variables.

> Let $Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,\cdots$ be independent random variables $\ldots$

I will take this as the assertion that the countably infinite collection of *events* $A_i = \{Z_i = +1\}$ is a collection of independent events.  Now, a countable collection of events is said to be a collection of
independent events if each *finite* subset (of cardinality $2$ or
more) is a collection of independent events.  Recall that
$n\geq 2$ events $B_0, B_1, \cdots, B_{n-1}$ are said to be independent events
if
$$P(B_0\cap B_1\cap \cdots \cap B_{n-1}) 
= P(B_0)P(B_1) \cdots P(B_{n-1})$$
**and** every finite subset of two or more of these events is a
collection of independent events.  Alternatively, 
$B_0, B_1, \cdots, B_{n-1}$ are said to be independent events
if the following $2^n$ equations hold:
$$P(B_0^*\cap B_1^*\cap \cdots \cap B_{n-1}^*)
= P(B_0^*)P(B_1^*)\cdots  P(B_{n-1}^*)\tag{1}$$
Note that in $(1)$, $B_i^*$ stands for $B_i$ or $B_i^c$
(same on both sides of $(1)$) and the $2^n$ choices 
($B_i$ or $B_i^c$) give us the $2^n$ equations.

For our application, $A_i = \{Z_i = +1\}$ and $A_i^c = \{Z_i=-1\}$,
and so checking whether the $2^n$ equations
$$P(A_0^*\cap A_1^*\cap \cdots \cap A_{n-1}^*)
= P(A_0^*)P(A_1^*)\cdots  P(A_{n-1}^*)\tag{2}$$
hold or not, is equivalent to checking that the
*joint* probability mass function (pmf) of $Z_0, Z_1, \cdots, Z_{n-1}$
factors into the product of the $n$ *marginal* pmfs at each and
every one of the points $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \cdots, \pm 1)$ which is
what you would be doing if you had never heard of independent
events, just about independent random variables.

Thus, the statement

> Let $Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,\cdots$ be independent random variables $\ldots$

does mean, among other things, that $Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,\cdots, Z_{n-1}$
is a finite collection of independent random variables. But, 
does the assertion

> For all $n \geq 2$, $\{Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,\cdots, Z_{n-1}\}$ is a set 
>   of $n$ independent random variables

imply that the
countably infinite set $\{Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,\cdots \}$ is a
collection of independent random variables?

The answer is Yes, because we know by hypothesis
that some specific finite
subsets of $\{Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,\cdots \}$ are independent random
variables, while any *other* finite subset, say $\{Z_2, Z_5, Z_{313}\}$,
is a subset of $\{Z_0, Z_1, \cdots, Z_{313}\}$ which are independent
per the hypothesis and so the subset is also a set of independent
random variables.

In your question, with each $a_i \in \{+1, -1\}$ and
defining $b_i = \prod_{j=0}^i a_j$ which is also in $\{+1,-1\}$,
\begin{align}
P(X_0 = a_0, X_1 = a_1, \cdots, X_n = a_n)
&= P(Z_0 = a_0, Z_1 = a_0a_1, Z_2 = a_0a_1a_2, \cdots, Z_n = a_0a_1...a_n)\\
&= P(Z_0=b_0, Z_1 = b_1, \cdots, Z_n = b_n)\\
&= \prod_{i=0}^n P(Z_i = b_i)\\
&= 2^{-(n+1)}\\
&= \prod_{i=0}^n P(X_i = a_i),
\end{align}
that is, all $2^{n+1}$ equations of the form $(2)$ hold.
Thus, for each $n \geq 1$, $X_0, X_1, \cdots, X_n$ are
*independent* random variables, and therefore the
countably infinite collection $\{X_0, X_1, \cdots\}$
of random variables is a collection of independent
random variables.

---

After reading over my revised answer, perhaps it is **I** who is
making the problem much harder than necessary. My apologies.

Comment: Since the question asks whether an *infinite* set of random variables is independent, it would seem that the sigma algebras involved *must* be infinite and cannot be finite.  Or do you perhaps have a theorem available that allows you to draw conclusions about independence of infinite collections of random variables based on the independence of finite subsets of them?

Comment: An infinite collection of random variables is said to be a set of independent random variables if _every_ finite subset is a set of independent random variables. At least, that's the definition that I was taught at first; the stuff about tail $\sigma$-algebras came later in a course on measure-theoretic probability. I think an argument can be made that if for each $n \geq 2$, $X_0, X_1, \cdots , X_n$ are independent random variables, then the infinite collection $\{X_0, X_1, X_2, \cdots\}$ is a collection of independent random variables.

Comment: Thank you!  That looks like such helpful information that you ought to consider incorporating it in your answer.

Comment: @whuber I have incorporated the argument into my answer. As you are aware, the standard shibboleth $$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = \prod_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)\tag{1}$$ cannot be used to say that the $A_i$ are a countable collection of independent events/random variables even if we interpret both sides of $(1)$ as the limit as the number of variables increases without bound. The limit is $0$ in either case.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. ... How do I state this precisely, if it is right? $\forall i \leq n, \sigma(X_i) \subseteq \sigma(X_n)$ ?

Your have the right idea, but I would recommend using the definition of the Markov property to state this, namely that we have $P(X_n\mid X_0,\dots,X_{n-1})=P(X_n \mid X_{n-1})$. There is nothing imprecise about this as long as you have a precise definition of conditional probabilities. The $\sigma-$algebra condition you wrote is not correct.

> 2. ...It seems like I assumed $X_n$ and $Z_{n+1}$ are independent. Are they?

Hint: measurable functions of independent random variables are independent (you decide if you need to prove this).

> 3. ...I'm stuck.
>
> Is what I've done right so far? Which parts are wrong? Where do I go from here?

Try structure your answer some more. Specify the events $B_i$ under consideration, e.g. notice that since each variable only takes 2 values there are not that many different types of events to consider.

First solve for the right hand side using, e.g., the argument that
$$P(X_i = 1)=\mathbb E P(X_i = 1 \mid X_{i-1})=\mathbb E 1/2=1/2;$$ you have the right value.

Then solve for the left hand side using the Markov property as you have attempted.

Comment: Thanks Student001. How do I show the process is Markov? What is the exact $\sigma$-algebra relation for the $X_i$'s? How do you know $P(X_i = 1 | X_{i-1}) = 1/2$ ?

Comment: i) You show it by checking the definition - don't bother with the $\sigma-$algebras. On points where $X_n = 1$, $X_{n+1}=1$ iff $Z_{n+1}=1$, and equivalently when changing to $-1$ in either place. But $Z_{n+1}$ is independent of $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Done with the Markov part (well, you write it rigorously). ii) Check the definition of $E \left( \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i = 1 \}} \mid X_{i-1}\right)$. Intuitively, it has to be 1/2 because $Z_i$ is independent of $X_{i-1}$ and takes each value with equal probability.

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to mention I already figured out Q3. Hehehe. Thanks. I'll try out Markov later.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you can't and I can add something to the answer later.